# Warning in production mode stops execution

Tags: magento2, error, contact-form, error-log, production-mode

I'm facing a weird issue.
I had to override the Magento_contact Post Controller. Just adding a field on the contact form and the redirect after form is submitted, something easy, and all goes okay on developer mode.

But when I changed to production mode, when I submit the form, it appears "There has been an error processing your request"

I see the report, but it's only a warning, I don't know where it comes... I attach the report at the end.

I remember that error ocurred when I was implementing that feature, I changed some lines (don't remember exactly what I did) and it seems that worked...

And now suddenly I wanted to try again and oh... the error again.

The question is: Why is stopping the execution if it's only a warning? Can I set some settings to just proceed when it's a warning?

And how you debug this? I just don't know how to handle when things break like that... if I set to developer it works...

If you wanna see the code:

```
<?php
namespace Sgi\Override\Controller\Magento_Contact;

class Post extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index
{

    /**
     * Post user question
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$post) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if ($error) {
                throw new \Exception();
            }

        $setFrom = [
                    'name' => $post['name'],
                        'email' => $post['email'],
                        ];

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeScope))
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
        ->setFrom($setFrom)
                ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('contact-us');
            return;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addError(
                __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('contact-us');
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And the report:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:163:"Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/EntityAbstract.php on line 152";i:1;s:7045:"#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'ltrim() expects...', '/home/magento-domain/p...', 152, Array)
#1 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/EntityAbstract.php(152): ltrim(Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager), '\\')
#2 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/EntityAbstract.php(81): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\EntityAbstract->_getFullyQualifiedClassName(Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager))
#3 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\EntityAbstract->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager))
#4 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#6 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php(136): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#7 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php(110): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->createGeneratorInstance('\\Magento\\Framew...', 'Sgi\\Override\\Co...', 'Sgi\\Override\\Co...')
#8 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Sgi\\Override\\Co...')
#9 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Sgi\\Override\\Co...')
#10 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): spl_autoload_call('Sgi\\Override\\Co...')
#11 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Sgi\\Override\\Co...', Array)
#12 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Sgi\\Override\\Co...', Array)
#13 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ActionFactory.php(40): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Contact...')
#14 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php(300): Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory->create('Magento\\Contact...')
#15 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php(161): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->matchAction(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Array)
#16 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(50): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->match(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#19 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#20 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#23 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#26 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#29 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /home/magento-domain/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#32 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /home/magento-domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#34 /home/magento-domain/public_html/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#35 {main}";s:3:"url";s:23:"/en/contact/index/post/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Comment: Run `rm -rf var/di/*` it will solve issue. If needed run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
rm -rf var/di/*
```

If needed run

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Okay, WHAT is happening? I run `rm -rf var/di/*` and it worked fine, then I run `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` and it broke again. And running these commands one by one it's not solving (Well I thought the command that sets to production mode runs all these commands except cache flush and reindex)... what is going on? seems that I have to compile and after delete `/di/` folder??? I'm freaking out

Comment: Only this command works fine `rm -rf var/di/*`

Comment: Well... but I want to know why. So you are compiling the code, and then you delete the `di` folder? that makes no sense...